# Форма отправки сообщения gmail

Tags: java, android, gmail

В моём navigationDrawer есть некий список, по которому я перехожу в активити.
Сейчас решил сделать так, чтоб при переходе в активность, меня сразу перебрасывало в форму отправки gmail, но почему то при переходе выдаёт диалоговое окно - unsupported action. не совсем понимаю что не так делаю, вот мой код активити.

```
public class ContactForm extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate( Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    sendFeedback();
}

private void sendFeedback() {
    Intent send = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO);
    String uriText = "mailto:" + Uri.encode("email@gmail.com") +
            "?subject=" + Uri.encode("the subject") +
            "&body=" + Uri.encode("the body of the message");
    Uri uri = Uri.parse(uriText);

    send.setData(uri);
    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(send, "Send mail..."));
}
```

}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуй на реальном девайсе протестировать, так как скорей всего в этом проблема, а именно потому что не установленны соотвествующие сервисы в эммуляторе.

Похожая ситуация:
[Смотреть здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31052350/6387618)

Comment: Да, получилось, спасибо. Но странно что в эммуляторе нету службы gmail.